# Need to get instance id from django in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to django and I have a problem.
I have a django form

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3']
        localized_fields = ('id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

When I try to output `id` it doesn't work, but it works with others.

```
{{form.id.value}}
```

How do I get the `id` value in template from the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The id is the primary key field, therefore it shouldn't change, and you shouldn't include it in your model form's `fields`.

You can display the value in the template with:

```
{{ form.instance.id }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ original.pk }}
```

is a variable referring to the form's object's id.